# Linq2SQL+Repository pattern: how to implement type related mapping

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm

I have the Repository pattern implemented to access DB data through the Linq2Sql ORM:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T, TDb> : IRepository<T>
    where T : IEntity
    where TDb : class, IDbEntity, new()
{
    protected RepositoryBase(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;

        _context = _container.Resolve<CMCoreDataClassesDataContext>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return GetTable().Select(GetConverter());
    }

    protected abstract Table<TDb> GetTable();
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TDb, T>> GetConverter();

    protected CMCoreDataClassesDataContext Context { get { return _context; } }

    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly CMCoreDataClassesDataContext _context;
}
```

Here is an example of particular Repository implementation:

```
public class CustomerProductRepository
    : RepositoryBase<ICommonCustomerProduct, CMCoreDAL.DbData.CustomerProduct>
{
    protected override Table<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CustomerProduct> GetTable()
    {
        return Context.CustomerProducts;
    }

    protected override Expression<Func<CMCoreDAL.DbData.CustomerProduct, ICommonCustomerProduct>> GetConverter()
    {
        return dbEntity => dbEntity.ProdId == (int)ProductType.ProductTypeEnum.CommonProduct
                    ? new CommonCustomerProduct
                    {
                        UnityContainer = UnityContainer,
                        InstanceId = dbEntity.InstanceId,
                        CustomerId = dbEntity.CustomerID,
                        StatusCode = dbEntity.StatusCode,

                        DeviceLicenses = dbEntity.DeviceLicenses,
                        ServerLicenses = dbEntity.ServerLicenses,
                    }
                    : new SpecificCustomerProduct()
                    {
                        UnityContainer = UnityContainer,
                        InstanceId = dbEntity.InstanceId,
                        CustomerId = dbEntity.CustomerID,
                        StatusCode = dbEntity.StatusCode,

                        UserLicenses = dbEntity.DeviceLicenses,
                    }
         ;
    }
```

Here SpecificCustomerProduct is inherited from CommonCustomerProduct.

Presented source code shows how records from DB are mapped to different instances according to instance type. There are a lot of common fields for these classes and only few of them are different.

I have 2 concerns for this code:

1. Some duplications of assignment operations;
2. Low readability: in order to add few more concrete classes I need to make unreadable chain:

   ```
   return dbEntity => dbEntity.ProdId == iType1
                   ? new Type1
                   {
                       ... assignments
                   }
                   : 
                   {
                       dbEntity.ProdId == iType2
                       ? new Type2
                       {
                           ... assignments
                       }
                       : new Type3
                       {
                           ... assignments
                       }
                   }
   ```

Is there any better way to implement 'type-related' mapping with such pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [LINQ to SQL's Inheritance mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399352.aspx)?  It allows you to map different classes to a common table, using a database column (type discriminator) to determine which type of object to generate.

Comment: Yes, I've looked. But I don't see how it can help me. I will still have access to table through the CustomerProductRepository class that receives in this case DB entities which I need to remap. And I don't see an easy way to remap DB entities to business entities. I don't see how 'data-specific' entities will help here.

Comment: What you'd need to do is define the SpecificCustomerProduct and CommonCustomerProduct entities in your dbml, and set up an inheritance association between those and CustomerProduct, which I assume is the entity you currently have defined in your dbml.  In the inheritance association, set CustomerProduct.ProdID to be the discriminator column.  Then when you do any query on the CustomerProduct table, the entities returned will automatically be of the inherited types - no mapping required.  To customize the inherited classes, create a separate partial class file for each class and edit away.

Comment: Guess, would be good to have a separate repository class for each inherited class (that could have base repository class for shared functionality). Am I right?

Comment: You know, I'm not sure about that.  I suppose you could first try using only the base class - LINQ to SQL will automatically generate the inherited types even if you query through the base-class table.  So if your CustomerProduct database table contains discriminator values for the inherited types, then a query like `context.CustomerProduct.ToList()` will contain a mixture of base and inherited types.  But as far as what to do with your repository code, I'm not sure.  That might make a good SO question...